# Every time soap producer changes there package name for version i have to update the import statements in all files, java

Tags: java, soap

In my project i am using soap services of other vendor.
When i get the generated java classes, it is like - **com.abc.v1.ABC.java**

So in my project i am using **import com.abc.v1.ABC.java** statement in all classes to import it.

Now the problem is for next version they are providing the class with different version like - **com.abc.v2.ABC.java** and to use it i have to update my all files import statement to com.abc.v2.ABC.java. 
Its a pain to do it for every version as we have to update it in more than 1000 files.

Can anyone please suggest any solution or any design pattern to get rid off from this import statement update ??

Comment: use the search-replace-pattern

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for your purposes but could you replace the import statements with "import com.abc.*"?

It seems the apparent design pattern for your problem would be to import a file (that you create and is always the same) which imports the new version - but Java doesn't 'inherit' imports so that approach is a dead end.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When i use com.abc.*; and compile the project, it fails to compile error is -- cannot find symbol class ABC.